# Cannot access control inside DetailsView Edit template

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

Hello everybody and thanks in advance,

Well, I have a DetailsView in my .aspx file and I can't access to a CheckBoxList control placed in the DetailsView's edit template. I've read a lot of threads about this but still can't find a solution. Here's the code...

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="MyDetailsView" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="DataMyDetailsView">
    ...
    ...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DATA" SortExpression="DATA">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <div style="width:400px; height:300px; overflow-y:auto">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="DataCL" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataEDIT" DataTextField="DATA" DataValueField="ID_DATA">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>
```

Then, in my .cs file I have this piece of code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        CheckItems();
    }
 }

...
...

public void CheckItems()
{
    CheckBoxList DataCL = (CheckBoxList)MyDetailsView.FindControl("DataCL");

    using (conexion)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conexion;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM DATA";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conexion);
        adp.Fill(ds);
        DataCL.DataSource = ds;
        DataCL.DataTextField = "DATA";
        DataCL.DataValueField = "ID_DATA";
        DataCL.DataBind();
```

The problem is that when the execution reaches the first line in which the control is called (DataCL.DataSource = ds;), a "NullPointerExeception" is thrown, however I can access easily to controls in ItemTemplate.

Please, can someone help me in this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, because this control is dynamically created after data binding. Instead attach your grid to `DataBound` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound(v=vs.110).aspx)) event and bind checked box list there

```
protected void MyDetailsView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyDetailsView.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        CheckBoxList DataCL = (CheckBoxList)MyDetailsView.FindControl("DataCL");

        using (conexion)
        {
            // your data bound code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, gzaxx, it worked!, thanks a lot, this issue it was driving me crazy!